Where or how do i store JWT access token in a next.js app router app?
I've got a backend that uses a JWT auth, when i log in, it sends me access token in the body of the response and refresh token in http-only cookies. I get the part with the refresh-token, it's attached on every request, fine, but what about access token. What's the most convinient way to store it?
The problem is i can't really use local storage nor cookies, and i don't wanna make the whole page 'use client', i could store it in the RAM, but access token would be flushed every time user refreshes the page, and the request to refresh the token would have to be made.
One way is to send acccess token the same way i send refreh token, but i think there should be something much more simple.
This is what i've got so far
"use server"

import { token } from "@/tokens"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function refreshToken() {
    const response: Response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:8000/auth/refresh-token",
        {
            credentials: "include",
            method: "POST",
            headers: { Cookie: cookies().toString() },
        }
    )

    if (!response.ok) return

    const body = await response.json()

    if (!body.access_token) return

    token.token = body.access_token
}

export async function authFetch(url: string, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response> {
    return await fetch(
        url,
        {
            headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token.token}`, ...init?.headers },
            cache: "no-store"
        }
    )
}

